# How to disable html input ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable input id of buttons in java script.
My code:

```
var uniqid = "idModify_" + index;
var buttonModify = $('<input type="button"/>');
buttonModify.attr('id', uniqid);
li.append(buttonModify);
buttonModify.button();
if (my required condition is true)) {
    $("#uniqid").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
}
```

I have tried `$(uniqid ).prop('disabled', true);`
it does not work.

Note: index value will be `0` to `n` every time the button gets added to li.

Comment: Try `$("#"+uniqid).attr("disab...`

Comment: Got it! thanks! @freedomn-m

Answer (score 1):

You need to create ID selector using the variable `uniqid`

```
$("#" + uniqid).prop("disabled", true).addClass("disabled");
```

Better to use already referenced object

```
buttonModify.prop("disabled", true).addClass("disabled");
```